# Sort product collection after load

Tags: product-list, sorting, sort

I have a module that shows some product that I want to sort by ID.

I'm trying the following code with no success

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc');
?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Collections inherit from the class

```
Varien_Data_Collection_Db
```

There's a method named `addOrder` on that class.

```
public function addOrder($field, $direction = self::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
{
    return $this->_setOrder($field, $direction);
}
```

So, you'd think something like this should work for basic ordering

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addOrder('entity_id');
```

However, it doesn't.  Because of the complex joining involved in EAV Collections, there's a special method used to add an attribute to the order clause

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection::addAttributeToSort
```

However again, this can only be used to add simple attributes.  To create an arbitrary sort, you'll need to manipulate the `Zend_Select` object directly.  I'm not a big fan of this, and I'm not a big fan of using custom mysql functions to achieve things, but it appears it's the only way to do this

I tested the following code on a stock install and got the desired results.  You should be able to use it to get what you want.

```
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        //shakes fist at PDO's array parameter
        $products->getSelect()->order("entity_id DESC");
        foreach($products as $product)
        {
            var_dump($product->getEntityId());
            var_dump($product->getSku());
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I get back on this question because I did not solved the problem yet.

What I need to do is sort a collection loaded by a product list block

 {{block type="catalog/Product_List" category_id="324" template="catalog/product/listwidgetnobadge.phtml" mode="grid" limit="6"}}

Comment: Hi @rohit :D , why something so simple as $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
$collection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    echo $item->getSku();
    echo $item->getCreatedAt();
    echo '<br>';
}
Could not be working for me? (I mean the sorting)

Comment: Forget about what I said, there was a third party observer who was reordering the product collection. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
             ->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC);
```